# Ubuntu 14.04 running extremely slow !

Tags: intel-graphics, performance

I have installed ubuntu 14.04 on my 8 pc's . 
Those running on pentium processors are fine but not as stable as they should . Windows 7 used to run extremely smooth on them . App executes slow , and sometime the system gets absolutely non responsive !

While I had two systems with 512 mb of ram and intel celeron processors , they used to run on windows 7 , and their performance was okey but as soon as i installed ubuntu 14.04 they are not responding . It takes 5 or more seconds to type a letter ,, a minute to open a app. They boot normally but as soon as i login , they respond like a hell !

Pls help me out for both errors . I have tried intel graphics driver installer and many tweaks but could not help ! Is there any issue with the ubuntu image selection or what ?? Its ubuntu 14.04.1 32 bit iso !

Comment: First stop much tweaking may be incorrectly! Check disk space for Ubuntu further `swap` partition may help you with only 512MB RAM.

Answer (score 0):

You should try debian on your 512mb RAM machines, it does not use up that much RAM. Also using a lighter desktop environment like LXDE should also help. But seriously 512mb RAM is way too less for a current high end system and will never run "good" on this hardware (my personal opinion).